# Does log4net run ok on .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: .net-core, log4net

[According to Apache](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html), it runs fine.

However, according to ApiPort, it has 10 calls that are not in .NET Core.

[image]

Am I not understanding something?

Comment: the types I see on screenshot are not related to log4net, but to the System namespace.

Comment: "According to Apache it runs fine" - it says that it supports only .NET Core 1.0

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo The listed items are what is referenced in log4net that does not exist in .NET Core 3.1 or earlier.